# PHP comments count

Tags: php, if-statement, count

I want if there are 0 comments that it shows: '0 comments', and when there are 2 comments it shows '2 comments'. But when there is online 1 comment that it shows '1 comment' without S at the ending.

How can I do that?

```
$counting = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `postid`='".$data['id']."'"));
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry I did research but didn't know what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ($counting == 1 ? $counting . " comment" : $counting . " comments")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($counting>1)
    echo $counting . ' comments';
else
    echo $counting . ' comment';
```